# PDF::Tk Background Image

Tags: perl, pdf-generation, pdftk

I have a code that spits out a bunch of lines of HTML, turns into PSLines, with turns into PDF Lines.  After the PDF lines I need PDF::Tk to insert a background image.

Below is my code, with a comment on where I think I need the code.  Can anyone help me with this code snippet?

```
sub printFilePdf {
    my $unique_id = shift;
    my ($file) = "$OUTFILES/$id.html";

    open(my $htmlFH, '<', $file) or die "Can't open file $file $!\n";

    my $processId = open2(\*POUT, \*PIN, qq(html2ps -U -f /home/apache/cgi-bin/test/html2psrc-tst));

    my @lines = <$htmlFH>;
    print PIN @lines;
    close PIN;

    my @psLines;
    while (<POUT>) 
    {
        chomp;
        push(@psLines,$_);
    }
    waitpid $processId, 0;

    $processId = open2(\*POUT, \*PIN, qq(ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter - -));
    print PIN "$_\n" foreach(@psLines);
    close PIN;

    my @pdfLines;
    while (<POUT>) {
        chomp;
        push(@pdfLines, $_);
    }
    waitpid $processId, 0;

    #Insert Code Here

    print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=driverhistoryrecord.pdf\n\n";
    print "$_\n" foreach(@pdfLines);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF::Tk is not exactly intuitive, `call_pdftk($INPUT, $OUTPUT, @ARGS)` executes `pdftk $INPUT @ARGS output $OUTPUT`... You can get help on what to feed to @ARGS from [man pdftk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk).

```
my $pdftk = PDF::Tk->new;
$pdftk->call_pdftk(\$PDF_AS_STRING, \$OUT, 'background', 'bg.pdf');

print "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=done.pdf\r\n\r\n";
print $OUT;
```

---

Alternatively you might want to take a look at something like [HTML::HTMLDoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3A%3AHTMLDoc) which has support for `<body background="bg.jpg">` and a `set_bodyimage($image)` function.

```perl
use HTML::HTMLDoc;
my $htmldoc = new HTML::HTMLDoc;
$htmldoc->set_html_content(<<"EOF");
<html><body>   
This is my <b>pdf</b>...
</body></html>
EOF

$htmldoc->set_bodyimage('bg.png');
print $htmldoc->generate_pdf()->to_string();
```